# Embed XAML.CS into Powershell WPF Tool

Tags: c#, wpf, powershell, xaml

Im currently working on a little tool that has multiple tabs, one of these tabs is a Profile Reset Tool. This is the current GUI
[image: GUI]

The powershell fully functions as I want it to however I do not have suitable XAML Code to handle Click Events. I know I can do this easily through the XAML.CS in C# however do not know how I would transfer that code over to the PS Script

The best solution would be to handle Click Events directly through the XAML but i'm not too sure what I would modify

Restart Machine

`<Button x:Name="NTRelease" Content="1) Restart Machine" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="386,164,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" Height="23"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=ProfileSelect, Path=Text.Length, Mode=OneWay}" Click="NTRelease_Click"/>`

Get Drives & Printers

`<Button x:Name="GetInfo" Content="2) Get Drives &amp; Printers" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="386,192,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" Height="23" IsEnabled="False"/>`

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to run powershell from C#? Perhaps you should look at delegate commands

Answer (score 0):

Disables a Button

```
$WPFButton.Add_Click({
$WPF.IsEnabled = $False
)}
```

Enables a button

```
$WPFButton.Add_Click({
$WPF.IsEnabled = $True
)}
```